# Build two anchor tags for one sentence

Tags: html

I have the following code,

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head>  
 <title>ProviderOne</title>  
 </head>
 <body>
 <table width="100%">      
 <tr width="100%">       
 <a href="javascript:redirectURL('20');"> this is one set of &lt;<a
 href="javascript:redirectAlertIndex('open questions');">questions.</a> . Click on this 
 link.</a>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My problem is as there are two hyper links. When I close the second hyper link,the other part "Click on this" is not hyper linked. I want that also to be linked, because i close the first link at the last. Why is my full word not hyper linked.

Can anybody else help me in solving this issue?

Comment: you forgot to close your first `a`tag or are you doing an `a` nested tag?

Comment: i am nesting the tags.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anchors inside anchors.
So you must set them like this:

```
<a>href 1</a> <a>href 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="some link">Click 1</a> 
<a href="some link">Click 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Links defined by the anchor tag must not be nested; an anchor tag must not contain any other anchor tag

in short You can't nest anchor tag